# If we roll a dice 10000 times and we gain 1€ if the result is odd, 2€ if it's 2 or 4 and 5€ if it's 6, what is the prob of gain 22000€ or more?

Tags: probability, dice

In the end I modeled a random variable as

```
   { 1 = 3/6;
     2 = 2/6; 
     5 = 1/6 }
```

And the situation is that we roll a dice 10,000 times and we want to know what is the probability of gain 22000€ or more assuming that roll a dice is *gratis/free*.

I was wondering if could I use the Central Limit Theorem and approximate the probability distribution as a Gaussian one. But I don't find the right parameters since I'm a beginner.

What kind of strategy should I use to answer this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expectation for the money gained by rolling a single dice is
$$\mu=\frac{3}{6}\times1+\frac{2}{6}\times2+\frac{1}{6}\times5=2$$
and the variance
$$\sigma^2=6-2^2=2$$

As 10000 is quite a large number, by the [central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), the sum of the money gained by rolling a dice 10000 times shall follow the normal distribution $N(10000\mu,10000\sigma^2)$

Hence, the answer to your problem shall be $1-\Phi(\frac{22000-10000\mu}{100\sigma})=1.044\times10^{-45}$, which is a very unlikely case.

Comment: OK so when I find a situation like that, I should multiply the mean ("mu") for the time I repeat the experiment, isn't it? The result however is kind "unbelievable". I mean, if the mean is 2, after 10000 we reach 20000. Adding "only" 2000 points is that difficult?

Comment: Yep, as long as you're doing the exact same experiment over and over again, the multiplication method will apply for both mean and variance. If you rolled the dice just a couple of times, it's quite normal to find the result 10% larger than the expectation. But if you rolled 10000 times, the result shall be "almost" as expected. That's what the law of large numbers is for :)

Comment: @BlacK: The standard deviation for the 10,000 rolls is $\sigma\sqrt{10000}\approx141$ and so 2000 more points is very hard to achieve!

Answer (score 2):

You have the probabilities and the payouts, so the next step would be finding the mean and variance. Mean is
$$
\mu=1\cdot3/6+2\cdot2/6+5\cdot1/6=2
$$
and variance is
$$
\sigma^2=(1-2)^2\cdot3/6+(2-2)^2\cdot2/6+(5-2)^2\cdot1/6=2
$$
if I have not made any mistakes.

Now you can apply the Central Limit Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_i$ denote the result of the $i$-th dice roll. Although you don't explicitly state this, I assume that the $X_{i}$ are independent. In order to use the Central Limit Theorem, you need to compute some quantities related to $X_{i}$.

$E[X_{i}] = 1 \cdot \frac{3}{6} + 2 \cdot \frac{2}{6} + 5 \cdot \frac{1}{6} = 2$

$E[X_{i}^{2}] = 1^2 \cdot \frac{3}{6} + 2^2 \cdot \frac{2}{6} + 5^2 \cdot \frac{1}{6} = 6$

$Var[X_{i}] = E[X_{i}^{2}]-E[X_{i}]^{2} = 6 - 2^{2} = 2$

You wish to compute:

\begin{align*}
P(\sum_{i=1}^{10000}{X_{i}} > 22000) &= P(\sum_{i=1}^{10000}{(X_{i}-E[X_{i}])} > 22000-10000 \cdot 2) \\
&= P\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{10000}{(X_{i}-E[X_{i}])}}{\sqrt{10000 \cdot Var[X_{i}]}} > \frac{2000}{100 \cdot \sqrt{2}} \right)
\end{align*}

Finally, the CLT states that:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(X_{i}-E[X_{i}])}}{\sqrt{n Var[X_{i}]}} &\approx N(0,1)
\end{align*}

Hence,

\begin{align*}
P(\sum_{i=1}^{10000}{X_{i}} > 22000) &\approx P(Z > 20/\sqrt{2}),
\end{align*}

where $Z$ follows a standard gaussian distribution.